# Iterating through model fields - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to **iterate through fields as they are written down within my model**:

currently I'm using this:

```
def attrs(self):
  for attr, value in self.__dict__.iteritems():
    yield attr, value
```

but the order seems pretty much **random** :(

---

Any ideas?

Answer (score 24):

The `_meta` attribute on `Model` classes and instances is a `django.db.models.options.Options` which provides access to all sorts of useful information about the `Model` in question.

For fields, it will give you them in the order they were created (i.e. the same order they were declared).

```
def attrs(self):
    for field in self._meta.fields:
        yield field.name, getattr(self, field.name)
```